# Jmeter : validating a log viewer result with sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am executing a jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler script in which console - log view i am getting a result in text for example check the below image INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Result1:Image not present
[image]

I need to validate the webdriver sample from that result . Any suggestion pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** want to read [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and look for the specific message in there you could do something like:

```
def log = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File('jmeter.log'), 'UTF-8')

if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase('Banner not present', log)) {
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Failed to locate message "Banner not present" in the log')
}
```

where `WDS.sampleResult` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) implementation and you can amend response code, message, mark the sampler as passed or failed and so on.

however it's better to do it on Groovy variable level, i.e.

```
if (!k) {
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

you can also consider relying on [Groovy Truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth), there is no need to declare booleans

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks a lot . it works with WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)